# What is the easiest and secure way to install openstack?

Tags: openstack

I'm trying to test and understand openstack for learning purposes, but I cant find the simplest and secure way of install openstack on my virtual machine that is running ubuntu 12.04 lts.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenStack installation guide for Ubuntu 12.04 can be found here: http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/

If you look here: http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/scripted-dev-installation.html - there is a scripted install.

But I have to confess I have not tried it myself. I need to understand OpenStack from an infrastructure point of view, so I am slogging through the install the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to try out Openstack is Devstack - an all-in-one installation of Openstack that runs on one machine.

Installation is pretty simple - you just grab the installation scripts from GitHub and run "stack.sh" - see here: http://devstack.org/

Alternatively, sign up for trystack - http://www.trystack.org/

Answer (score 1):

Barak's suggestion of using DevStack is the best way to learn about OpenStack.  You can also use Vagrant, which allows you to create a VM and setup and run DevStack in easy steps (and is a cool way just to spin up VMs).

https://github.com/bcwaldon/vagrant_devstack

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked there has been lots of updates in the topic, including the Autopilot.

But if you want, not only to get the thing running in the easiest way, but also to learn how it works, there is also [BOMSI](http://github.com/julenl/BOMSI), which is basically an scripted version of the official documentation, written in BASH. And it even has a Graphical User Interface.

BOMSI generates self-installing ISO files, which will set up the whole thing after the first reboot.

Installing a 3 node virtual environment on a Ubuntu (or Debian based) machine is as simple as:

```
git clone https://github.com/julenl/BOMSI.git   
cd BOMSI/CentOS7-Kilo/
for N in controller compute1 network; do ./bomsi-iso.sh -n=$N; done
```

Answer (score 0):

An other choice is to use NanoStack (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00F2NNR3C)) on Amazon EC2. This is a PAID AMI but it's pretty cheap. You won't need to do any installation or configuration. It just works. It's great for learning purpose.